# Is there a way to declare a root resource for each jsp?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, view

I have multiple spring MVC project that I will need to combine into one...
but say I have two folders of static resources that conflict, so i need to keep them separate:

What i do is declare two resource mapping:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/web1" mapping="/web1/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/resources/web2" mapping="/web2/**"/>
```

and in my web1 jsp I do:

```
<link href="/web1/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/web1/css/test1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/web1/css/test2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but what if i need to group my jsp, say i have web1a.jsp, web1b.jsp, web1c.jsp, and i want them all to use the web1/ resource mapping.

Is there a faster way to declare it, like a property that i can put on top of the JSP to declare that the root source is web1 instead of manually adding "web1/" for each tags? Something like:

all jsp that uses web1,

```
<%@root="web1/" %>
<link href="/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/test1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/test2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

so that i could retain the original reference without modifying each individual tags

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you could do that, but how about `<link href="${root}/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">` and then provide the value of `root` via jstl tags/functions or some bean?

Comment: You can add the root element as a variable tag and set it in link while rendering <link href="${root}/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @Thomas,@Abdul, thank you, that could work but I'm looking for a way to be able to set the root without editing each tag... the projects are just handed down to me, and they contain a _lot_ of static references

Comment: To change `<link href="/web1/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">` to `<link href="/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">` you'd have to edit the tags anyway, so I don't see any huge difference. If you trust your sources you could use some search-and-replace to make it easier. The problem with _static_ references is that they _are_ static, i.e. unless there's some expression in them the JSP engine will render them as they are. Thus just setting a root wouldn't help anyway, the only things you can is use the expression, specialized tags or some post processing (aka automated search-and-replace).

Comment: @Thomas, if i have no choice, then that would do it, search-and-replace each references... thank you